# User defined instances in CLIPS

Tags: instance, clips

Can anyone help me out please?
We have an assignment and we're trying to create a recycling software which sorts trash (instance) according to it's attributes (both of which the user inputs using bind).
So for example the user inputs "Beer Bottle" and the software asks the user some questions, like "Is the trash made of glass?"
If yes, it continues with the questions and adds the attributes to the instance based on the answers (like in this case attribute material would have the value "glass"), until it sorts the trash as "GLASS (yellow container, number 3...)" and writes it back to the user so one can know how to dispose of the trash.
So what we are struggling with is the part where the user is supposed to input the instance.
We want the user to add the "instance name" and the programmer will create an instance with the given name, in this case BEER BOTTLE, and will assign it attributes like container_color, container_number or something of the sort. I added the non functional code, but maybe it will help you understand what we're trying to accomplish.
If anyone could help us out it would be much appreciated. In advance I'd like to thank you for your time.

````
    (slot NAME (type SYMBOL))
    (slot RISK (type SYMBOL))
    (slot SEPARATING(type SYMBOL)) 
    (slot ABBREVIATION (type SYMBOL))
    (slot COLOR (type SYMBOL))

(defrule type_trash
=>
(printout t "Type in trash:" crlf)
(bind ?trash (read))
(make-instance ?trash of TRASH (name) (risk) (separating))) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I found an answer to this. For anyone wondering about the same thing, it can be done  like this `(make-instance ?trash of HEAVIER_TRASH (name ?trash)(weight "higher than 10 kg"))` and then you can print it out using  `(send (symbol-to-instance-name ?trash) print)`.